# AngularJS single page app - load default template and navigate to another page on login success

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

Here I have 3 Pages
Index.html,Login.aspx,MainPage.html
 when i run the Application it shows Login.aspx and when i enter the Credentials it Renders to MainPage.Here is My Snippet

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head >
        <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="BaseController.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
     <div data-ng-view="">   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and My Login.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html data-ng-app="myApp">
<html >
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="BaseController.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body  >

    <div data-ng-controller="loginController">

    <h3>LOGIN</h3>
    UserName:<input type="text" data-ng-model="userName" /> <br />
    Password:<input type="password" data-ng-model="password" /><br />
    <button type="button" data-ng-click="login()">Submit</button>
        </div>

</body> 
</html>
```

and BaseController.js is

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
function ($routeProvider,locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'Login.aspx',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })
    .when('/MainPage', {
        templateUrl: 'MainPage.html'
        })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    $locationProvider.html5mode(true);
}]);
app.controller('loginController', function ($scope,$location) {
    $scope.login = function () {
        var uname = $scope.userName;
        var pwd = $scope.password;
        if ($scope.uname == 'admin' && $scope.pwd == 'admin') {
            $location.path("/MainPage");
        }
    };
});
```

when i Run the App i get Index page only...is there any mistakes..

Answer (score 0):

**try this at the place of**

```
$location.path("/MainPage");
```

replace with

```
window.location = "#/MainPage.html";
```

Comment: thanx for ur Response... i want to when i run the Page first displays Login page..but i get Index Page only..

Comment: He has configured route for the app and injecting template, why he need to call MainPage.html? He just need to set route path so that angular will take care of injecting template and binding controller.

Answer (score 0):

It's "$locationProvider" at line 3 of your controller not "locationProvider"

**Change this**

```
 $locationProvider.html5mode(true);
```

**To this**

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true,
          requireBase: false
    });
```

method name is html5Mode, i.e caps **"M"**

**Single Page login app**

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<!-- <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script scr="basecontroller.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div data-ng-view="">   </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

**Login.aspx**

```
  <div>

    <h3>LOGIN</h3>
    UserName:<input type="text" data-ng-model="userName" /> <br />
    Password:<input type="password" data-ng-model="password" /><br />
    <button type="button" data-ng-click="login()">Submit</button>
     </div>
```

**basecontroller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$locationProvider','$routeProvider', 
function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true,
          requireBase: false
        }); 
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'Login.aspx',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })
    .when('/MainPage', {
        templateUrl: 'MainPage.html'
        })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    /* $locationProvider.html5mode(true); */

}]);
app.controller('loginController', function ($scope,$location, $window) {

    $scope.login = function () {

        var uname = $scope.userName;
        var pwd = $scope.password;
        if (uname == 'admin' && pwd == 'admin') {

            $location.path('/MainPage'); 
        }
    };
});
```

**MainPage.html**

```
<div>Main Page</div>
```

So when you start the app login template will be loaded onto index.html and then on entering "admin" as username and password it will navigate to MainPage.html

Comment: @Pratap..i Changed it..but when i run App first Appears Index Page Only

Comment: @iDontKnow : What are you seeing in index page?? Login form ryt?

Comment: No,in index page nothing there only  <div data-ng-view="">   </div> ,Login Form in Login.aspx

Comment: I asked when you run the app what are you seeing? I am able to get login page and navigating to main page by entering "admin" "admin"

Comment: what i need is i want to Create one Login Form and When i enter Credentials its Redirect to next page.thisis my Requirement.but in one Artice i read <div data-ng-view=""> </div> is put in Another page.so i create one more page(IndexPage.html)

Comment: @iDontKnow : updated my answer, follow the steps with code

Comment: @pratap.it displays  Index Page only.can u provide simple example of Login Form and redirects to next page in Button Click

Comment: @iDontKnow : Take a look, i have created working plunker for you
http://plnkr.co/edit/d14LoH6hoBMBZo8ahtdO?p=preview...... Do remember this is not a code sharing site, we will just guilde/help in cases of confusions or doubts.